# Position of chapter number in thesis

Tags: formatting, numbering

[image]I need to shift up the chapter number and title my thesis in the attached image.

I am using the Thesis template from https://altitude.otago.ac.nz/cs-department/otago-thesis-latex-template

```
%% This is the package ``otagothesis''.  Read the file
%% otagothesis.README for information regarding options and usage.
%%

\ifx\ProvidesPackage\undefined
\def\ProvidesPackage#1[#2 #3 #4]{%
\wlog{LaTeX Package `#1' #3 <[![enter image description here][1]][1]#2> #4}}

\fi
\ProvidesPackage{otagothesis}
       [1998/02/03 v0.99 Otago's A4 based page layout]
\ifx\documentclass\undefined
\else
  \DeclareOption{widemargins}{\WideMargins}
  \DeclareOption{phd}{\PhD}
  \DeclareOption{msc}{\MSc}
  \DeclareOption{ma}{\MA}
  \DeclareOption{mcom}{\MCom}
  \DeclareOption{interimsci}{\IS}
  \DeclareOption{interimarts}{\IA}
  \DeclareOption{interimcom}{\IC}
  \DeclareOption{dipsci}{\DS}
  \DeclareOption{diparts}{\DA}
  \DeclareOption{dipcom}{\DC}
  \DeclareOption{bschons}{\BScHons}
  \DeclareOption{bahons}{\BAHons}
  \DeclareOption{bcomhons}{\BComHons}
  \DeclareOption{notables}{\NoTables}
  \DeclareOption{nofigures}{\NoFigures}
  \DeclareOption{nolibrary}{\NoLibrary}
\fi

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                      option processing stuff                      %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\PhD{%
%%PhD is the default: do nothing
}

\def\MSc{%
  \renewcommand{\thesistype}{Master of }
  \renewcommand{\faculty}{Science}
}

\def\MA{%
  \renewcommand{\thesistype}{Master of }
  \renewcommand{\faculty}{Arts}
}

\def\MCom{%
  \renewcommand{\thesistype}{Master of }
  \renewcommand{\faculty}{Commerce}
}

\def\IS{%
  \renewcommand{\fulfilment}{submitted in partial fulfilment of the degree of}
  \renewcommand{\thesistype}{Master of }
  \renewcommand{\faculty}{Science}
}

\def\IA{%
  \renewcommand{\fulfilment}{submitted in partial fulfilment of the degree of}
  \renewcommand{\thesistype}{Master of }
  \renewcommand{\faculty}{Arts}
}

\def\IC{%
  \renewcommand{\fulfilment}{submitted in partial fulfilment of the degree of}
  \renewcommand{\thesistype}{Master of }
  \renewcommand{\faculty}{Commerce}
}

\def\DS{%
  \renewcommand{\fulfilment}{submitted in partial fulfilment of the}
  \renewcommand{\thesistype}{Postgraduate Diploma in }
  \renewcommand{\faculty}{Science}
}

\def\DA{%
  \renewcommand{\fulfilment}{submitted in partial fulfilment of the}
  \renewcommand{\thesistype}{Postgraduate Diploma in }
  \renewcommand{\faculty}{Arts}
}

\def\DC{%
  \renewcommand{\fulfilment}{submitted in partial fulfilment of the}
  \renewcommand{\thesistype}{Postgraduate Diploma in }
  \renewcommand{\faculty}{Commerce}
}

\def\BScHons{%
  \renewcommand{\fulfilment}{submitted in partial fulfilment of the degree of}
  \renewcommand{\thesistype}{Bachelor of }
  \renewcommand{\faculty}{Science, with Honours}
}

\def\BAHons{%
  \renewcommand{\fulfilment}{submitted in partial fulfilment of the degree of}
  \renewcommand{\thesistype}{Bachelor of }
  \renewcommand{\faculty}{Arts, with Honours}
}

\def\BComHons{%
  \renewcommand{\fulfilment}{submitted in partial fulfilment of the degree of}
  \renewcommand{\thesistype}{Bachelor of }
  \renewcommand{\faculty}{Commerce, with Honours}
}

\def\NoTables{%
  \newif\if@notables \@notablestrue
}

\def\NoFigures{%
  \newif\if@nofigures \@nofigurestrue
}

\def\NoLibrary{%
  \newif\if@nolibrary \@nolibrarytrue
}

%% Define widemargins option for margin notes
\def\WideMargins{%
  \newdimen\ExtraWidth
  \ifcase \@ptsize
    \ExtraWidth = 0.5in
    \@widemargins
  \or
    \ExtraWidth = 0.5in
    \@widemargins
  \or
    \ExtraWidth = 0.7in
    \@widemargins
  \fi\let\WideMargins\relax\let\@widemargins\relax}
{\def\do{\noexpand\do\noexpand}
 \xdef\@preamblecmds{\@preamblecmds \do\WideMargins}
}
\def\@widemargins{%
    \global\advance\textwidth by -\ExtraWidth
    \global\advance\marginparwidth by \ExtraWidth
    \if@twoside
      \tw@sidedwidemargins
    \else
      \@nesidedwidemargins
    \fi}
\def\tw@sidedwidemargins{%
    \if@reversemargin
      \@tempdima=\evensidemargin
      \advance\@tempdima by -\oddsidemargin
      \advance\oddsidemargin by \ExtraWidth
      \advance\oddsidemargin by \@tempdima
      \advance\evensidemargin by -\@tempdima
    \else
      \advance\evensidemargin by \ExtraWidth
    \fi}
\def\@nesidedwidemargins{%
    \if@reversemargin
      \advance\oddsidemargin by \ExtraWidth
      \advance\evensidemargin by \ExtraWidth
    \fi}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%           Stuff to be done before option processing               %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%
%% Default to PhD
%%
\newcommand{\fulfilment}{a thesis submitted for the degree of}
\newcommand{\thesistype}{Doctor of }
\newcommand{\faculty}{Philosophy}

%% default to having a list of tables or figures
\newif\if@notables \@notablesfalse
\newif\if@nofigures \@nofiguresfalse

%% default to having the library decleration form
\newif\if@nolibrary \@nolibraryfalse

%% We always use a4 paper
\paperheight 297mm
\paperwidth  210mm

%% Shift default TeX reference point to top LH corner
\hoffset -1in
\voffset -1in

%% Set top margin to 1.5cm
\topmargin  15.0mm

%% If we use running headers, restrict them to one line of text. 
\headheight 12pt

%% Use no more than a double line between header and body.
\headsep    25pt

%% Now set height of text body according to point-size
\ifcase \@ptsize
    \textheight 53\baselineskip
\or
    \textheight 48\baselineskip
\or
    \textheight 45\baselineskip
\fi
\advance\textheight by \topskip

%% we must always have 30mm binding margin
\textwidth      155.0mm
\marginparwidth 0.0mm
\if@twoside
  \oddsidemargin  30.0mm
  \evensidemargin 25.0mm
\else
  \oddsidemargin  30.0mm
  \evensidemargin 30.0mm
\fi

%% some stuff for the splash page
\def\dob#1{\gdef\@dob{#1}}
\def\@dob{\@latex@error{No \noexpand\dob (date-of-birth) given}\@ehc}

\def\address#1{\gdef\@address{#1}}
\def\@address{\@latex@error{No \noexpand\address given}\@ehc}

\def\department#1{\gdef\@department{#1}}
\def\@department{\@latex@error{No \noexpand\department given}\@ehc}

\def\fullname#1{\gdef\@fullname{#1}}
\def\@fullname{\@latex@error{No \noexpand\fullname given}\@ehc}

%% Now that we've done all the hard stuff, run the Options code.
\ifx\documentclass\undefined
\else
  \ProcessOptions
\fi

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%           Stuff to be done after option processing                %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%
%% We need to specify the titlepage exactly
%%
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{35mm}
\parbox{100mm}{
\center
\linespread{1.5}\LARGE \@title \par
\vspace{10mm}
\large \@author \par
}
\vfill
\linespread{1.5}\normalsize
\fulfilment \large \par
\thesistype \faculty \par
\normalsize at the University of Otago, Dunedin, \par
New Zealand. \par
\bigskip
\@date
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\cleardoublepage
}

%%
%% We need a really simple ``Abstract'' environment
%%
\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
  \vspace*{45mm} \begin{center} {\bf \abstractname}
  \end{center} \begin{quote} \linespread{1.3} \normalsize \par}
  {\end{quote} \linespread{1}}

%%
%% And a nice simple ``Acknowledgements'' environment
%%
\newcommand{\ackname}{Acknowledgements}
\newenvironment{acknowledgements}{%
  \vspace*{45mm} \begin{center} {\bf \ackname}
  \end{center} \begin{quote} \linespread{1.3} \normalsize}
  {\end{quote} \linespread{1}}

%%
%% We want ``References'', not ``Bibliography''
%%
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

%%
%% We need to redefine thebibliography so as to include
%% it in the contentspage. Otherwise it is exactly as in report.cls
%%
\def\bibliography#1{%
  \if@filesw
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibdata{#1}}%
  \fi
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}\bibname}%
  \@input@{\jobname.bbl}%
}%

\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#1: #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa > 0.8\hsize
    \leftskip = 0.1\hsize
    \rightskip = 0.1\hsize
    #1: #2\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}

%%
%% \frontstuff is here to put in the titlepage, list of figures, etc.
%%
\newcommand{\frontstuff}{%
\if@nolibrary
%% do nothing
\else
{\parindent 0pt
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center} {\bf Library Declaration Form} \\
\IfFileExists{logo.pdf}{%
\includegraphics[height=2cm]{logo.pdf} \\
}{}
University of Otago Library
\end{center}
\vfill
\begin{tabbing}
\noindent Author's full name and year of birth: \= \kill\\
\noindent Author's full name and year of birth: \@fullname,\\
\hspace*{1cm} (for cataloguing purposes)\>\@dob\\
\end{tabbing}
\vfill
Title of thesis: \@title \\
\vfill
Degree: \thesistype \faculty \\
\vfill
Department: \@department \\
\vfill
Permanent Address: \@address \\
\vfill
I agree that this thesis may be consulted for research and study purposes
and that reasonable quotation may be made from it, provided that proper
acknowledgement of its use is made.\\
\vfill
I consent to this thesis being copied in part or in whole for
\begin{list}{\roman{enumi})}{\usecounter{enumi}}
\item a library
\item an individual
\end{list}
at the discretion of the University of Otago.\\
\vfill
\hspace*{5cm}Signature:\\
\vfill
\hspace*{5cm}Date:
\cleardoublepage
}
\fi
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}
\maketitle
\if@twoside
  \setcounter{page}{3}
\else
  \setcounter{page}{2}
\fi
\IfFileExists{abstract.tex}{%
\begin{abstract}
\input{abstract}
\end{abstract}
}{}
\cleardoublepage
\IfFileExists{acknowledgements.tex}{%
\begin{acknowledgements}
\input{acknowledgements}
\end{acknowledgements}
}{}
\tableofcontents
\if@notables
%% do nothing
\else
  \listoftables
\fi
\if@nofigures
%% do nothing
\else
  \listoffigures
\fi
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
}

%%
%% End of file `otagothesis.sty'.
```

Comment: If you are using a template, maybe you need to stick to those rules.  Academic institutions do not usually like people playing around with their formats

Comment: `oragothesis.sty` has no chapter title  layout commands. How did you  obtain this one?

Comment: I would agree with Mario, but I am not sure the issue is from the .sty file - perhaps a MWE would help?